# How to get the build number from other build configuration (for example B) without increasing the B build number in Teamcity

Tags: build, version-control, dependencies, teamcity, build-numbers

I have 2 build configuration named A and B.I want to use the build number of build config B in the build step of A. And I don't want a change to be made in the build number of B (that is, it won't be built again.)
Only when the build number of B is changed, there is a real change in project B.

i tried snapshot dependency, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the dependency property, you can use `%dep.<DependencyExternalId>.<property.name>%` syntax. In your case, `<property.name>` would be `build.number`, so `%dep.<DependencyExternalId>.build.number%`.

You mention that you tried snapshot dependency and it didn't work. It's not clear what you mean by that, but the common case could be that even though `A` depends on `B`, when `B` is finished, `A` will not be triggered automatically. You need to either trigger `A` instead of `B` (and since `B` depends on `A`, `A` will be triggered too or reused if possible), or use a [finish build trigger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-finish-build-trigger.html) in `A`